# Multivariable Function Optimization with Semidefinite Hessian Matrix

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, quadratic-forms, hessian-matrix

I'm writing to ask for support in carrying out an exercise about the optimization of a multivariable function.
The function is: $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2z+z^2-2x$ 
Clearly the domain is $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $f$ is infinitely differentiable on it. 
Well... I started to calculate critical points. It turned out to be only one of them, which is: $P=(1,0,0)$.
Then I determined the Hessian Matrix: $Hf(P=(1,0,0))=\begin{pmatrix}2
 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 
 &0  &0 \\ 0
 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$ 
It's associated to a positive semidefinite quadratic form, so the point $P=(1,0,0)$ must be a local minimum or a saddle point, but we can't conclude anything more.
I thought to calculate the sign of the increment $\Delta f=f(x,y,z)-f(P)=x^2+y^2z+z^2-2x-(-1)=(x-1)^2+y^2z+z^2$, in a neighbourhood of $P$. 
Firstly I translated the axes (with the substitution $u=x-1$), and then I tried to use spherical coordinates. I guess $P=(1,0,0)$ is a local minimum, but I'm not sure. I would be grateful if someone could show me how to rigorously prove the nature of this critical point. 
Thank you so much for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Define the curve $\mu(t) = (1,0,|t|^{3/2})$. Now, investigate the composite functions $f \circ \mu$ near $t=0$.

Comment: As you suggested I tried to calculate: $f(1,0,t)=-1+t^2>-1$ for $t\neq 0$. Instead: $f(1,t,t)=-1+t^2+t^3$ which is $>-1$ in some neighbourhood of $P=(1,0,0)$, since $t^3=o(t^2)\: \: for \: \: t \mapsto 0 $. So I investigated the behavior of $f(1,t,t^3)=-1+t^5+t^6$. There exist a neighbourhood of $P=(1,0,0)$ where $f<-1$, because $t^6=o(t^5)\: \: for \: \: t \mapsto 0$. So $P=(1,0,0)$ is a saddle point. Thank you!

Comment: @user773458 my bad, the previous hint was incorrect because I made a sign error in my head which is why i thought they would work... but turns out both of those curves have local minima at t=0. This curve after the edit will show that t=0 is indeed a saddle

Comment: Thank you so much!